# link listview to another activity

Tags: android-listview

```
package com.example.libtracker;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
     private LibactivityMainActivity studentDBoperation;
     private TextView editText1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        studentDBoperation = new LibactivityMainActivity(this);
        studentDBoperation.open();


         List values = studentDBoperation.getAllTriptakerActivity();                    
              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
              setListAdapter(adapter);

    // connecting listview to another activity              
     try {
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            new String[] {"activity_main"}));
     mlistView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text 
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      String sText = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

      Intent intent = null;
      if(sText.equals("activity_main"))
      intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),TriploggerActivity.class);
      //else if(sText.equals("Help")) ..........

      if(intent != null)
        startActivity(intent);              
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  });
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    } //end of connecting listview to another actovity



         public void addUser(View view) 
        {

                ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();

                EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                TriptakerActivity stud = studentDBoperation.addTriptakerActivity(text.getText().toString());

                adapter.add(stud);
            }
          public void deleteFirstUser(View view) {

                ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
                TriptakerActivity stud = null;

                    if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0)
                    {
                    stud = (TriptakerActivity) getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                        studentDBoperation.deleteTriptakerActivity(stud);
                        adapter.remove(stud);
                     }
          }



    @Override
            protected void onResume() {
            studentDBoperation.open();
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
            protected void onPause() {
        studentDBoperation.close();
            super.onPause();               


       // public void linkclickview(View v)
       //// {
            //Intent i = new Intent(this,TriploggerActivity.class );
            //startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

`

This is the code that I want to use to connect or link to another activity, but it is not working.
Please kindly help me out. Thanks